# Nested SharedWorkers

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Is it possible (even if unwise) to instantiate a SharedWorker inside the handler for another SharedWorker?

```
// Code in sharedworker.js
onconnect = function(e) {
  var port = e.ports[0];
  port.onmessage = function(e) {
    port.postMessage("Hello"); // This is sent.
    var worker = new SharedWorker("worker.js");
    post.postMessage("Goodbye"); // In my tests, this is not sent.
  }
}

// Code in main.js
var worker = new SharedWorker('sharedworker.js');
worker.port.onmessage = function(e) {
  window.console.log(e.data);
}
worker.port.postMessage("Start");
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the [`SharedWorker` interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#shared-workers-and-the-sharedworker-interface) is only exposed in `Window` contexts. You can't create a `SharedWorker` directly from inside another `SharedWorker` nor from inside a dedicated `Worker`.

```
[Exposed=Window]
interface SharedWorker : EventTarget {
  constructor(USVString scriptURL, optional (DOMString or WorkerOptions) options = {});

  readonly attribute MessagePort port;
};
SharedWorker includes AbstractWorker;
```

What you can do however is to start both `SharedWorker` instances from the same `Window` context and pass to both of them a `MessagePort` from a [`MessageChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageChannel) object. This way, both your `SharedWorker` instances will be able to communicate one with each other directly, just like if one did instantiate the other:

In your window's script you'd then have something like:

```js
const a = new SharedWorker("worker-a.js");
const b = new SharedWorker("worker-b.js");
const { port1, port2 } = new MessageChannel();
a.port.postMessage("", [port1]);
b.port.postMessage("", [port2]);
```

And in you worker scripts:

```js
onconnect = (e) => {
  const winPort = e.ports[0];
  winPort.onmessage = (e) => {
    const workerPort = e.ports[0];
    workerPort.onmessage = (evt) => {
      // do something with messages received from the other SharedWorker
    }
    workerPort.postMessage(someData, transferables);
  };
};
```

Unfortunately, StackSnippets iframes don't allow to create a `SharedWorker`, so I have to outsource the [live demo](https://imminent-kind-cattle.glitch.me/) into a [Glitch project](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/imminent-kind-cattle).

Answer (score -2):

Should that be `port.postMessage("Goodbye");` instead of `post.postMessage("Goodbye");`?

Comment: This should be a comment since it doesn't answer the question